Formula to Count Unique Values Based on Criteria in Another Tab
I have a spreadsheet with three tabs. First is Report, second is July24 and the third is July23. The July tabs are dumps of raw data and the Report tab uses those to pull through information. One thing I'm stuck on is, counting the number of unique account numbers on July24/23 in column B based on the employee name in column A. So for example:



A Employee
B Account Number




John
55


John
55


John
78


John
78


Lisa
12


Lisa
12


Lisa
12


Ash
89


Ash
87


Ash
88


Ash
81


Ash
82


KarlAM2
101


KarlAM2
101


KarlSW
102


KarlSW
102


KarlSW
103


KarlE
104



So on the Reports tab, column A is Employee, column B is Unique Accounts. John's unique accounts should be 2, Lisa 1, Ash 5. It seems like it should be very simple but I just can't work it out. I've tried many different variations of formulas and the only one that has shown anything other than an error is:
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE('JULY 24'!A:A,"=John",'JULY 24'!B:B)), 0)
which is showing a value of 0.
So if someone could send me the formula I'd need to get Dave showing at 2 or let me know exactly where I'm going wrong, I can work out the rest from there.
EDIT
I left out some additional information, thought I'd be able to solve this bit myself after working out the other issue. I have one employee who has multiple values in column A on July24 which then all need adding together in Report. So Karl will have rows as KarlAM2, KarlE, KarlSW etc. Solved this in other areas on report by adding them all together. So on the Report tab column B is turnover and added all of Karl's data using this (G on July24 is gross amount£ per customer sale):
=SUMIFS('JULY 24'!G:G, 'JULY 24'!A:A, "=KARLAM2")+SUMIFS('JULY 24'!G:G, 'JULY 24'!A:A, "=KARLE")+SUMIFS...   etc.
So will need an overall count of Unique B values too for all of his account combined.
On the reports tab I would expect it to show like this



A Employee
B Turnover
C Unique Accounts Ordered




John
£12000
2


Lisa
£8000
1


Ash
£57000
5


Karl
£36000
4




There are many options here, I chose to use GROUPBY() for simplicity:

Formula in D2:
=GROUPBY(IF(LEFT(A2:A19;4)="Karl","Karl",A2:A19),B2:B19,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE(x))),,0)

Or if applicable:
=GROUPBY(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A19,"\B[A-Z\d]+$",),B2:B19,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE(x))),,0)


Nice Sir, you are fast I would have gone for GROUPBY() otherwise.

I don't think GROUPBY would work here, I left out some additional information, thought I'd be able to solve this bit myself after working out the other issue (will edit original post). I have one employee who has multiple values in column A on July24 which then all need adding together in Report. So Karl will have rows as KarlAM2, KarlE, KarlSW etc. Solved this in other areas on report by adding them all together like this
=SUMIFS('JULY 24'!G:G, 'JULY 24'!A:A, "=KARLAM2")+SUMIFS('JULY 24'!G:G, 'JULY 24'!A:A, "=KARLE")+SUMIFS... etc.
So will need an overall count of Unique B values too.

@BradenA8, so how does a function know do distinguisch 'KarlE' from (hypothetically) 'Karley'. In other words, on what factors would I know to not take the 2nd name into a total for 'Karl'?

In the raw data we only have 5 employees that will ever be in column A. Of those 5 only Karl will have alternative names. So John, Lisa, Ash and Nicola will show in that exact same way for each unique customer and each transaction those customers have had. But for Karl, he will only ever show in one of the variations, so KarlAM2, KarlE, KarlSW, KarlNW, KarlNE etc. No value in A will ever show as just Karl. Each unique account number will only ever show against one employee name. So 101 won't ever show for John or KarlE or any other Karl variations, only ever against KarlAM2 name.

Edited the answer @BradenA8

Using GROUPBY() does makes it easy and simpler to read, perhaps one other alternative :


=LET(
     _A, A2:A13,
     _U, UNIQUE(_A),
     HSTACK(_U, MAP(_U, LAMBDA(α, ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B13,_A=α)))))))


Edit: Post edited by OP, with new update.
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$19,1-ISERR(FIND(D3,A$2:A$19)))))


Or, instead of using ROWS() can use SUM() as well:
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$19,1-ISERR(FIND(D3,A$2:A$19))))<>""))


Or, Spill with one single dynamic array formula:
=MAP(D3:D6,LAMBDA(α,
 ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B19,1-ISERR(FIND(α,A2:A19)))))))




The above formula should work with the new updates, however there are chances it may return false positives because the conditions usage is based on names, and it may happen there can be employee with same names. Therefore, it will be better if we can use some other alternatives along with the first name to use as a conditions.

Update with the Excel Formula that works with Excel-2019


=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(D3,A$2:A$19)),1/COUNTIF(B$2:B$19,B$2:B$19),0))


Or,
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(1-ISERR(FIND(D3,A$2:A$19)),1/COUNTIF(B$2:B$19,B$2:B$19),0))



I haven't used the LET function before, so I'm not sure how it will interact with my other issue that I've edited into my original post.

Hi @BradenA8 , I have supplied updated answer refer above, but once answers already posted, shouldn't be updating post. Nevermind, for the record please dont do it. Thanks =)

In the raw data we only have 5 employees that will ever be in column A. Of those 5 only Karl will have alternative names. So John, Lisa, Ash and Nicola will show in that exact same way for each unique customer and each transaction those customers have had. But for Karl, he will only ever show in one of the variations, so KarlAM2, KarlE, KarlSW, KarlNW, KarlNE etc. No value in A will ever show as just Karl. Each unique account number will only ever show against one employee name. So 101 won't ever show for John or KarlE or any other Karl variations, only ever against KarlAM2 name.

Also, thank you for the heads up about posting rules. I've come back to working with data after 6 years and it's the first time logging in here since then! So very rusty with my excel skills and stack overflow etiquette! Thank you though, I'll look through and test your answer tomorrow. Appreciate the support.

@BradenA8 no issues at all. Its only because to make everyone aware we are same page, one can forget to update what they have actual query, bt its okay. just wanted to inform so that others don't think, we are deviating ! Thanks!

Managed to do some quick tests before I left and have followed your instructions exactly, even setting up a dummy tab to post the test data in the same was as your screenshot. But I keep receiving "That function isn't valid" errors. I don't know if it's because I'm on Excel 2019? Would that make a difference? Apologies, if it does I probably should have specified that up front.

@BradenA8 well yes, those functions are included in MS365 and excel for web, let me update the workaround for you! Updated the answer for Excel 2019!

Another way, using tables and named ranges,  (adjust the values to match your data):



Name
Range or formula




acct
='July 23'!$B$2:$B$500


acct_row
=ROW(acct)-ROW(INDEX(acct,1,1))+1


emp_name
='July 23'!$A$2:$A$500


is_uniq_acct_row
=IFERROR(N(INDEX(FREQUENCY(acct,acct),acct_row)>0),0)


turnover
='July 23'!$G$2:$G$500





Functions used here should work in Excel 2019 - I haven't had a chance to test.
Number of rows in acct, emp_name and turnover should match.
FREQUENCY gives the count for each value on the first row of the value, this is used to identify the unique account rows
Enter alternate names in a table named alt_name :
For report, add a table report and in the first cell

of turnover : =SUMPRODUCT(turnover * ([@Emp] = IFERROR(VLOOKUP(emp_name, alt_name, 2, FALSE), emp_name)))
of Unique Accounts : =SUMPRODUCT(is_uniq_acct_row * ([@Emp] = IFERROR(VLOOKUP(emp_name, alt_name, 2, FALSE), emp_name)))



